# Migration from SQL table with no ids

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm trying to migrate from a SQL table using migrate module.
The fields in the table are a unique file hash (media), an url, a drupal internal path.
In the class extending SqlBase I have this function:

```
  public function getIds() {
    // The row property that represent the unique id for the id map.
    $ids['media'] = array(
        'type' => 'integer',
        'alias' => 'm');
    return $ids;
  }
```

It seems that *migrate* only accepts integers and **requires** ids to fill its migration map.
Is there a way to migrate with a string hash or without any id?

Answer (score 0):

You do have to have an ID - and you can use your hash here simply by defining it with 'type' => 'string'.

Comment: If I do this I get 
`PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'my_unique_string' for column 'sourceid1' at row 1`
This is because it tries to insert the string in _sourceid1_ field in _migrate_map_mymigrationid_ table, which is a INT field

Comment: Fixing getIds() to make the ID a string does not rewrite the existing map and message tables - you need to drop them so they'll get regenerated with the right (string) schema.